# Counting related elements without using distinct with Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I've got the following schema in my django models:

```
class CompanyModel(Model):
    name = CharField('name', max_length=75, db_index=True)
    logo = ImageField('logo', upload_to='company_logo/', blank=True,)

class OfficeModel(Model):
    company = ForeignKey(CompanyModel, related_name='office_company', db_index=True)
    address1 = CharField('address 1', max_length=50,)
    address2 = CharField('address 2', max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = CharField('city', max_length=50, db_index=True)
    state = CharField('state', max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES, db_index=True)
```

I want to get the list of states with the number of companies there. The problem is that I'm using MySQL, distinct over a field is not supported and a company could have many offices in a single state.

This is my fiers approach:

```
office_query.values('state').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('-count')
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `CompanyModel.objects.values("office_company__state").annotate(count=Count("id")).order_by("-count")`

Comment: Did not work: if a company has 2 offices in the same state, is counted double.